# Drawing vertical lines in android

Tags: android

i try to draw vertical lines in android.

```
DrawView drawView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    setContentView(drawView);

}

public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawLine(0, 100, 0, 0, paint);

    }

}
```

What this draw just one line. What i want to do draw this lines in whole screen. How can i do that? It must draw everywhere in screen vertically. It now draws vertically but just one.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? I mean, why you want to draw vertical lines on the screen? And what do you mean by *everywhere*? If you draw lines *everywhere* (as I understand it), it is the same as setting the whole screen red.

Comment: I just want, why are u ask that?

Comment: Because maybe that's not the right solution to your problem. Anyway, what do you mean by *everywhere*?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/198/screenshotfrom201303281q.png/ this is what i want. Sorry i cannot put image by uploading here because of my rank

Comment: How much separation you want between each line?

Comment: Check [Canvas#drawLines](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLines%28float[],%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far from your desired use case, I don't see any reason for you to use a custom view for this.  You can set a custom background with repeat enabled:

**res/drawable/MyBackground.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/lines_image"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Then for your view, set the background:

**res/layout/whatever.xml**

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/MyBackground" />
```

OR

```
myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.MyBackground);
```

lines_image.png should be a 20px (or however much space between you want) wide image with your red line on the right.

It's an important concept for UI development.  Don't do complicated things in code when a simple image solution will suffice.

**If you absolutely **MUST** Do this in code,** Then you just do the drawing in a loop for the width of the canvas.

```
private static final int LINE_SPACING = 20;

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getWidth(); x += LINE_SPACING) {
        canvas.drawLine(x, 0, x, canvas.getHeight(), paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2205733 Example added - you can set the background in code, as well - but I added the canvas method too.

Comment: so may ask one thing mode ? So can i add here if user use portait mode, canvas does this?

Comment: @user2205733 after a rotation, the onDraw methods of any views on screen will be called again, (unless you specifically interrupt it) supplied with a new canvas.  So if in portrait your canvas' size is 768x1024, after rotation your onDraw will be called again with a canvas of size 1024x768

Comment: how do i make this also horizontal?

Comment: What parameter i need to change to do that?

Comment: @user2205733 as in making boxes? or as in either horizontal or vertical?